# Display an icon with get_post_meta?

Tags: images, post-meta, icon

I want to display an icon in the post meta data in the loop.php, for each post have a specific meta_value!

To be more specific i use this code to display an icon when a new posts has been published and this lasts for 24 hours:

```
<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>
<span class="new-post"></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is the code in style.css:

```
.item-list span.new-post {
padding-left: 20px;
width: 20px;
height: 18px;
background: 0px 0px url(http://www.e-win.gr/wp-content/themes/e-win/images/new-post.png) no-repeat;
}
```

What exactly i want is display an icon when a post has a specific meta_value. Here is the code i am trying to reach it but with no results:

```
<?php $icon = get_post_meta(apaitei_logariasmo_facebook); ?>
<?php if( ! $icon == attr_esc(Ναι) ) ?>
<span class="facebook-badge"></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is the code i use in style.css to insert the icon:

```
.item-list span.facebook-badge {
padding-left:20px;
width: 20px;
height: 14px;
background: 0px 0px url(http://www.e-win.gr/wp-content/themes/e-win/images/facebook-badge.png) no-repeat;
}
```

What do i have to do to make the code work and display the icon for the specific meta_value?

P.S. I am using this `attr_esc(Ναι)` because i use Greek chars in the meta_value. Also i am using the "Advanced Custom Fields plugin" to create and manage custom fields.

This is the whole loop.php:

```
    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="post-0" class="post not-found post-listing">
    <h1 class="post-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'tie' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

      <?php else : $count = 0;?>
      <div class="post-listing <?php if( tie_get_option( 'blog_display' ) == '2col' )  echo"archives_2col" ?>">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>
      <?php if( tie_get_option( 'blog_display' ) != 'full_thumb' ): ?>
<article class="item-list <?php echo'item_'.$count; ?>">
  <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta">

       <?php 
            if( get_field( "hmeromhnia_lhkshs" ) ): ?>
            <span class="date"><?php the_field('hmeromhnia_lhkshs'); ?>     </span>  
       <?php endif; 
     ?>

     <?php 
            if( get_field( "wra_lhkshs" ) ): ?>
            <span class="time"><?php the_field('wra_lhkshs'); ?></span>   
       <?php endif; 
     ?>

     <?php tie_get_time() ?>

    <span class="category-label">
    <?php
    $caturls = array();
    foreach( (get_the_category()) as $cat ):
    $caturls[] = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID  ) . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a> ';
    endforeach;
    echo implode( ', ', $caturls );        ?></span>

    <span class="post-comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'tie' ), __( '1 Comment', 'tie' ), __( '% Comments', 'tie' ) ); ?></span> 

    <?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>
    <span class="new-post"></span>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php $icon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', true); ?>
    <?php  if( !empty($icon) ) : ?>
    <span class="facebook-badge"></span>
    <?php endif; ?>


    </p>


    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'blog_display' ) == 'content' ): ?>
    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Read More &raquo;', 'tie' ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>         
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php tie_thumb('',200,200); ?>
            <?php tie_get_score( true ); ?>
    </a>
    </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><?php tie_excerpt() ?></p>
        <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'tie' ) ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php tie_include( 'post-share' ); // Get Share Button template ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </article><!-- .item-list -->
   <?php if( $count == 2 &&  tie_get_option( 'blog_display' ) == '2col' ): $count = 0; ?>
    <div class="sep"></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
       <?php else: ?>
   <article class="item-list">
    <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>         
    <div class="post-thumbnail single-post-thumb archive-wide-thumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php tie_thumb('', 620 , 330 ); ?><?php tie_get_score( true ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta">
        <?php tie_get_time() ?>
        <span class="post-comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'tie' ), __( '1 Comment', 'tie' ), __( '% Comments', 'tie' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php echo tie_views(); ?>
    </p>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><?php tie_excerpt() ?></p>
        <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'tie' ) ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php tie_include( 'post-share' ); // Get Share Button template ?>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article><!-- .item-list -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for *get_post_meta* that you are using in incorrect. It is [documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

You need to pass a string for the second parameter. So, for example, use

```
$icon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', true );
```

Instead of

```
$icon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, apaitei_logariasmo_facebook, true );
```

---

In addition, string literals **must** be between the quotes in PHP.

```
if( $icon == esc_attr( 'Ναι' ) ) :
```

So, the solution is:

```
<?php
$icon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', true );
if( $icon == esc_attr( 'Ναι' ) ) : ?>
<span class="facebook-badge"></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ,using the corrections you gave me i succeeded displaying the icon. But now i can see that all the posts have the icon. I want only the posts that have the specific `'meta_value' -> 'Ναι'`. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Probably because i am using Greek characters. What if i use this: `if( $icon == attr_esc('Ναι') ) :`  ?

Comment: No it didn't work..

Comment: "Ναι" means "Yes" in English. But in the custom field i insert "Ναι" and not "Yes", because i want to display it in Greek. Here i have a query that finds the posts that have the `'meta_value' -> 'Ναι'` and displays them in a custom category. Here is the code:

`$args = array(
             'post_type' => 'post',
             'meta_key' => 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook',
    'meta_value' => esc_attr('Ναι'),
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged
    );`

Comment: that query i am using it in a custom category to retrieve all the post that have `'meta_key' => 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', 'meta_value' => esc_attr('Ναι')` in a loop. Just saying that using the `esc_attr('Ναι')` i can use Greek characters.

Comment: Okay. Maybe some of the logic around the snippet you provided isn't working. Do you mind expanding your answer up there?

Comment: Expanding it where?

Comment: I updated the main question with the loop.php

Comment: I found the solution! Here it is:

`<?php $icon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', true);
if( $icon == esc_attr('Ναι') ) : ?>
<span class="facebook-badge"></span>
<?php endif; ?>
`